# PHP check if the dates are in current week

Tags: php, wordpress

I am using WordPress as my CMS. 
I am trying to check if some of my user has a birthday in current week. 
with no success.

Here is my code

```
$fd = date("Y-m-d",strtotime('monday this week')); 
$ld = date("Y-m-d",strtotime("sunday this week"));

$cdate = date('m-d',time()); 
if (($cdate >= $fd)  && ($cdate <= $ld)) {
echo 'true';
} else {
echo 'false';
}
```

This is returning false for me 
If  i use

```
  'm-d' in $cdate variable
```

It works fine if is use Y-m-d 
but in that case , the years should be same which isnt possible as all the people have different birth years

Comment: in most cases, something like `if(date('W', $birthday) == date('W')){}`should be enough.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

**Here's My Way**

To find it you can do like this

**Step 1 :**

Find the Start and Last Day of the Week

```
$FirstDay = date("Y-m-d", strtotime('sunday last week'));  
$LastDay = date("Y-m-d", strtotime('sunday this week'));
```

**Step 2 :**

See if the given date is between the Start and Last Day of the Week

```
  if($Date > $FirstDay && $Date < $LastDay) {
       echo "It is Between";
    } else {
        echo "No Not !!!";  
    }
```

> If `Yes` then It belongs Else `Not`

So, Finally the Code you shall have is

```
<?php
$Date = "2015-06-01"; #Your Own Date
$Date = date('Y-m-d'); #Or Current Date Fixed here
$FirstDay = date("Y-m-d", strtotime('sunday last week'));  
$LastDay = date("Y-m-d", strtotime('sunday this week'));  
if($Date > $FirstDay && $Date < $LastDay) {
   echo "It is Between";
} else {
    echo "No Not !!!";  
}  
?>
```

**Note**

1. You can have your own Start Day i.e., `Sunday` or `Monday`
2. You can have your own Date or Current Date

Answer (score 13):

You can use the format parameter `W`, which will give you the number of the current weak in the year (the calender week).

```
if(date("W") == date("W", $birthday)){
    // User has birthday this week
}
```

`$birthday`have to be a timestamp here. Maybe you have to use `$birthday = strtotime($birthdate);`.

Comment: This is the most elegant solution IMO

Comment: This not working if you have the same number of the week but different years!

Answer (score 1):

Richard's answer is spot on. Just for people who reach this post looking for how to check the week is the same and also check that the year is the same; this will also check they are not only in the same week of the year, but the same year also.

```
$testData = "1447672336";
if((date("W") == date("W", $testData)) && (date("Y") == date("Y", $testData))){
    // The timestamp in $testData is the same week of the same year as today is.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, the easiest solution is to pass strings to date and keep them as a number, as you can see in this example:

```
$fd = strtotime('monday this week'); // First date
$ld = strtotime('sunday this week'); // last date

$birthday_date = strtotime('YYYY-mm-dd'); // Birthday date

if (($birthday_date > $fd) && ($birthday_date < $ld)) {
  echo 'true';
} else {
  echo 'false';
}
```

Of course, you'll have to change the birthday year to the current one.